# How do I set a value to the Session in asp.net on an onClick event of a normal htmlElement?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

I need to make a Function that receives a Session Key and a Session Value and call this function on a normal HTML onClick event. When this function is called the Session variable is assigned the Key I sent with the Value I sent. So far I have this:

```
<script runat="server" type="text/C#">
        protected void setSessionValue(string key, string value)
        {
            Session[key] = value;
        }  
</script>
```

But when I try to call if like so:

```
onclick="setSessionValue('itemID','3345');"
```

Its not working and giving me an error. Any help? I'm using c# and asp.net but I can't use code behind and need to work everything off the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to find a solution on my own thanks to all of your submissions, listen to this. I added a javascript function as follows:

```
function setSessionValue(key, value) {
     $.post('setSession.aspx?key=' + key + '&value=' + value);
}
```

and added an aspx file with the following code within it:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<% 
    Session[Request["key"]] = Request["value"]; 
%>
```

Basically this worked just fine, all I needed was a little jQuery. Thanks to all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set anything to the session from the client because session in stored on the server.

Comment: Ok, is there any way at all to set call a server side function that does this? I need this to 'fire' when I press an onClick event and to send specific key/value information according to which onClick event is pressed. I don't mind if it means that the page needs to be refreshed.

Comment: Then you need to make a postback or ajax call to your page. Check out this article: http://weblogs.asp.net/mnolton/archive/2003/06/04/8260.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call the *server side* (C#, VB.NET) code from the *client side* (Javascript).

This is not possible.

You can change your HTML control to be server side, by adding the `runat="server"` attribute on it - you will also need to change the type to one that is recognized serverside, namely [`<asp:HtmlLink />`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmllink.aspx).

Comment: I added a 'runat="server"' attribute to my element (in this case an <a> tag) and it gave me a 'tag isn't well formed' error. any idea why? my <a> tag is within a databound object that needs to retrieve the session value from the database.

Comment: @William Calleja - Can you post the complete tag into your question as an update (you can edit your question to do so). BTW - my answer has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to invoke a server method from a client side javascript. You can either do as what Oded suggested or, you can use the ASP.NET Ajax to achieve the same.

The below link would be a good starting point on how to do this using ASP.NET Ajax.

[ASP.NET Ajax Exposing Webservices to Ajax](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/Tutorials/ExposingWebServicesToAJAXTutorial.aspx)

Update 1:

[Another useful link](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/06/aspnet_ajax_invoke_a_static_me.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`OnServerClick="setSessionValue('itemID','3345');"`

instead of

`onclick="setSessionValue('itemID','3345');"`